# bitvector VS integer in Z3

Tags: z3

I implemented a z3 using fixedpoint phi(Real,Real, Int,Int,Int,Int) and add some rules into the fixedpoint. It gave me an answer, however, when I change the Int type into BitVector type,it can not solve the problem, and finally "time out". I have thought it would be faster using bitvector instead of int, however, it is not true, why?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using DL_ENGINE=1. This invokes the PDR engine which is 
currently only tailored for pure Boolean variables and linear real arithmetic 
(and often also works for linear integer arithmetic).

Comment: you are right, I am using DL_ENGINE=1,and when I run the program, it doesn't show any bug,just "time out".However, when I remove the "DL_ENGINE=1", it shows the bug said there is unbound var in the rule.I used ctx.mkbound() to created the bounded variable, I don't why there is such a bug?

Comment: BTW, is there any detailed description of INI parameters, I find i don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

DL_ENGINE=0 invokes a bottom-up datalog engine. It uses finite tables 
so it handles bit-vectors and booleans in the domain of the tables.
The two current options are:

```
DL_ENGINE=0: use a Datalog engine for saturation. It works for finite domains.
DL_ENGINE=1: use a PDR engine.
```

The tutorial on http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial/fixedpoints 
illustrates examples using these two options.

Comment: Thanks, so if there is Real, DL_ENGINE=0 is not suitable for it, right? because Real is not a finite domain